# Unable to open port on Win7 machine

Tags: windows-7, proxy, firewall, port

I'm trying to run [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) as a proxy on my machine. I want the browser on my Android device to access the internet through it. Now I've opened exceptions for both Privoxy and port 8118 (which is the one it's using) in Windows firewall but for some reason can't access it. `netstat -an` says `TCP    192.168.2.101:8118     0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING` but when I check it from outside it appears not to be. [This](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) tool says it's closed, and telnet from the Android gives `Error while reading socket`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the port forwarded through your router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `0.0.0.0:0` doesn't look right (it's not a valid IP address!!). The problem is likely with that (I would provide advice/tips on that, but I don't know what this particular IP is for).

But some help I can provide: I would also suggest, in the meantime, trying port 80 (HTTP port).

If your android uses Telnet, i suggest also trying port 23 (Telnet TCP port).
In any case, you *may* need to open the ports on your router too. For example, the router I have has a "virtual server" feature (yours may be slightly differently named). With this, I can specify public and/or private ports and PC (uses IP address, so you would need a DHCP reservation, read on for more) to use as a server, in your case a proxy server.

So if you login to your router and look for the virtual server page (or whatever your routers evuivelant of this is, refer to your user manual), and enter the IP address of your proxy server (the windows pc with privoxy), and open the ports (I'm not certain how this would work, as I don't know what router you have) private: 23; public: [leave blank]. If it won't allow you to leave public port blank, enter 80 (or 23 if that fails).

DHCP reservations:
To ensure your server PC always has same IP address, go to your DHCP settings (there should be an option for setting a DHCP reservation). Enter your PC mac address and name, and the same IP you used in the previous step. click save and make sure it's enabled. You may need to release or revoke the old IP address

(**HINT**: DHCP reservation only works if the reservation is within the DHCP range (i.e. most routers use a range of `192.168.0.2` (`192.168.0.1` is the routers IP address, and never changes) to either `192.168.0.100` or `192.168.0.254`)

Good luck, I hope this helps! If not, leave a comment and I'll look further into the issue and provide further help and advice. Likewise, if you don't understand something, leave a comment and I'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an external machine on your LAN to access Privoxy you must do the following steps:

1. Options -> Edit Main Configuration -> config.txt -> 4.1. listen-address -> add a listen address for the computer running Privoxy so it will be available to external machines (eg listen-address  192.168.0.1:8118)
2. Save config.txt
3. Restart Privoxy
4. Set each device that you wish to use Privoxy to use a HTTP proxy on port 8118 with the proxy address set in step 1